# Create akka system where all actors have references to each other

Tags: scala, mpi, akka, actor, message-passing

I want to create a program that starts multiple process on multiple machines in a homogenous environment on a cluster computer.

I want to use Akka 2.1 which ships with Scala 2.10.

What would be the best way to start an actor system in which all processes have a list of all actors across the system?

It needs to be able to start via ***mpirun*** so there should be a 1 to 1 correspondence between processes and actors.

Comment: One actor is no actor, says Carl. Your question title does not match up with the main text, it seems that you have a preconceived notion of a solution but do not share the underlying problem you are trying to solve. In this sense: what exactly is the question you would like to have answered?

Comment: I achieved this now. I can share the knowledge and re-edit the question to be more to the point if we reopen the question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe you're ever going to be able to get the actor (instance) / process correspondence. A key aspect of Akka's design is that actors are not tied to any particular thread. They get assigned a thread when they need one and there is one available.